# When does the ISS have a loss-of-signal?

Tags: iss, communication

The ISS has a camera mounted streaming live video from space ([HDEV](http://www.ustream.tv/channel/live-iss-stream)). From time to time, there is a blue screen visible, which is noted to be during times of "loss of signal". What exactly defines a "loss of signal"? Does the ISS have to be in line-of-sight contact with a ground station (which does not seem to the correct answer) or a different satellite? How is the ground communication done for this live video feed?

Answer (score 17):

The ISS communicates with ground assets through a robust network including ground stations and geostationary satellites ([TDRSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracking_and_Data_Relay_Satellite_System)). However, due to line of sight constraints there are brief gaps in coverage.

(edit - expansion)

These gaps can be seen (at least during the Shuttle era) by looking at the [Flight Plan](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/johnson/pdf/438131main_FLT_PLN_131_F_1.pdf). I've cut-n-pasted the relevant parts of one page from the linked STS-131 Flight Plan to give an idea of how often comm outages occur.  Take a look at the link to see what a full page of the Plan looks like.  Basically I've cut out all the activity information.

[image]

These timeline sections of the Plan show the GMT and Mission Elapsed time at the top, the Day/Night cycles, the orbit count, etc. (The top values are for the shuttle, the bottom ones are for the ISS).

The lines labeled TDRS W (west), E (east), and Z (Zone of Exclusion) show horizontal black bars when the associated Tracking and Data Relay Satellite (TDRS) is in line-of-sight with the shuttle's comm system.

The lines labeled TDRS AVAIL show when any of the satellites are available to the ISS comm system.  The gold bar is Ku-band (video) availability, the green bar is S-band (voice and data) availability.

This graph shows the brief periods during which there is loss of voice or video comm due to line-of-sight constraints with the TDRS system.

For more info on the ISS comm system see my answer to this question: [Do antennae on the ISS have to constantly move to maintain data links?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/16569/do-antennae-on-the-iss-have-to-constantly-move-to-maintain-data-links/16570#16570)

Comment: Incidentally, it's remarkable how if you google "ISS Loss of Signal" you get mostly UFO garbage.

Comment: Because of not finding any useful information I asked this question here. But then, do these "loss of signal" periods happen in always the same regions over earth? Or does it change? Using your answer, I would expect the loss-areas to be in approx. always the same regions over earth...

Comment: @Alex Only if TDRSS is not an option for communication in the ISS' position at the time. Keep in mind that the TDRSS sats are in much higher orbits, so loss of signal happens only when the ISS lacks a line of sight to *either* a ground station *or* one of the TDRSS sats, *or* when no TDRSS sat with line of sight to the ISS has line of sight to a TDRSS ground station. Because of the orbit disparity between the ISS and the TDRSS sats, this happens in different ISS ground-track locations for each orbit of the ISS.

Comment: Periodic loss of signal would happen in the same ground-track location if TDRSS was unavailable, because in such a case all that would matter was ISS line-of-sight to a ground station. The fact that we have TDRSS adds complexity to the predictions, but it is still perfectly possible to accurately predict when the ISS will suffer a loss of signal due to line of sight constraints.

Comment: @OrganicMarble *"..if you google "ISS Loss of Signal" you get mostly UFO garbage.."*  I was hoping the *answer* was going to be 'when it crosses the Bermuda Triangle'..  ;)

Comment: During times of "Loss of Signal"there should be no comm link! Why is there audio when no video, shouldn't it be the same comm sat?

Comment: *OM*: I've asked a [related question](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/16569/12102)

Comment: @Bagobolts the comm system is complicated but video is normally carried by the Ku-band system and voice is normally carried by the S-band system.  Different antennas on the ISS and comsat, different systems.

Comment: Clearly it is not about the satellite's signal that it transmits or how is received on the ground. The "Loss of Signal" now only happens in night times at the moment(I'm not sure what the situation was bacn in 2013 when this forum was opened. Surely the camera is not operated directly on solar, even so... there should be some sort of battery system, perhaps not due to the expense of getting it there. The point is, it does not make sense for the camera to lose the signal when entering night.