# How exactly does the live feed from ISS work?

Tags: iss, communication, communication-satellite

Using my cell phone in a city to download lots of data very fast is common, thanks due to the dense net of base stations close to me (~1 km).

But with the space station about 400 km above ground and moving fast, how is that downlink of the live stream established exactly? I am especially interested in the HD live stream from the space station. If the communication [as explained here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Space_Station#Communications_and_computers) is almost continuous, why is the live stream sometimes broken for a longer time? Does a broken live stream also mean, that a voice communication is interrupted between the astronauts and the ground station? And what bandwidth is used for the live HD stream?

Comment: There may be some useful information [in this answer](http://space.stackexchange.com/a/16570/12102) to the question [Do antennae on the ISS have to constantly move to maintain data links?](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/16569/12102) Also see the question and answer which I've linked to there.

Comment: I think they only stop the feed while the aliens are passing by a porthole.