# What is the function of this (apparently) fixed dish on the ISS?

Tags: iss, antenna, identify-this-object

I saw this image in [Popular Science](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNvm4.png), one of the example photos from the book by astronaut/photographer/astrophotographer(?) Donald Pettit. It's beautiful and impressive not only from a color/composition perspective, but also from a purely engineering perspective.

I noticed there is a fixed dish antenna, so I've included a cropped/magnified/rotated view of it for detailed examination. I'm wondering what it would be for, since it does not appear to have any, or at least much steerability.

What is it for? Which way does it point? Roughy what wavelength/frequency might it operate?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Kudos to you for noticing a spare part simply due to a "lack of ability to swivel" in a picture where 99.5% of people would just say "neat"! I certainly did not notice that at first glance hah.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

That's a spare part - a spare Space to Ground Antenna dish for the Ku band. It's mounted on an External Stowage Platform.  It was brought up on STS-127.

From the [STS-127 Press Kit](https://www.nasa.gov/pdf/358018main_sts127_press_kit.pdf) Mission Objectives (p 17) (emphasis mine):

> Install Integrated Cargo Carrier (ICC) to Payload Orbital Replacement Unit Accommodation (POA)
>
> - Remove and replace six Port 6 batteries (spacewalk)
> - Transfer PM-2, Linear Drive Unit (LDU) and **Space-to-Ground Antenna (SGANT)** to External Stowage Platform-3 (spacewalk)

Here's a shot of it in the payload bay.

[image]

And here are the transfer ops in progress

[image]

All those other ORUs (Orbital Replacement Units) you see mounted on those platforms are spares as well. The last group of shuttle flights brought up many external spares to cover failures of parts that were too large for the remaining logistics vehicles.

Comment: Beat me to it. I was also reading about [this other SGANT spare on STS-132](https://www.nasaspaceflight.com/2010/05/atlantis-eva-1-sgant-installation-center-stage/).

Comment: Yeah, there are a whole bunch of spare parts stuck to the outside of the ISS.

Comment: Redundancy, redundancy, redundancy.

Comment: Planning for lack of space shuttle to carry up big parts.

Comment: Yep, now I'm wondering how good of condition spares stay when not in use.

Comment: IIRC, STS-132 installed a working backup SGANT.  I think the STS-127 SGANT is the only "cold spare".

Comment: Possibly better or at least larger photos here: https://www.forumastronautico.it/index.php?PHPSESSID=nhtja9thmljp0lvgoaianl0ep7&topic=10782.msg108555#msg108555

Comment: Related answer: https://space.stackexchange.com/a/16570/12102

Comment: The spaceflight.nasa.gov gallery (abandoned by NASA in favor of flickr, sigh) has awesome pictures.  I shrank them down for this answer.

Comment: Mystery solved. That was quick, thanks! Looking again now, probably to a trained eye that could look like a storage area. I thought it might be an experimental breadboard area with various test being done.

Comment: I was the lead shuttle robotics instructor to the STS-127 crew, so I'm fairly familiar with that ORU :)  One of my favorite missions.

Comment: Oh! I remembered you've mentioned having a special fondness for certain STS missions, now I'm getting the picture why :)

Comment: So... where are the working antennas?

Comment: @SF. See the question that uhoh linked in the comments for a full description.

Comment: How far beyond currently available platforms capacity is the SGANT antenna?  I couldn't find anything on its size or mass.

Comment: @DanNeely The SGANT is six feet in diameter. Just an SGANT itself could maybe be carried in the Dragon trunk. But look in the payload bay picture and imagine the number of Dragon trips it would take to carry all that stuff.  Some of the spares like the Flex Hose Rotary Couplers are pretty big in themselves. There is one centered on the ELC4 grid in the picture in the question.

Comment: @SF. you can see one of them actually tracking a TDRS satellite in this video! https://youtu.be/PJzjs4EI22k

Answer (score 10):

To complement: The SGANT is the antenna that transmits high data rate signals, including many up/down video feeds, from/to the ISS. There is a total of 3 antennas: 2 at the end of booms on the Z1 trust, and the spare that you have identified. The active SGANT transmits/receives data by pointing to a TDRS satellite continuously for a portion of an orbit (~120 degrees), then transitions to a different TDRS via ephemeris and a spiral search pattern. They have been designed and built in Canada by SPAR/MDA, same with the ISS S-band antennas, and sold to L3-C (all ISS communications) and then Boeing. As far as I know, the SGANT is the only way to exchange video with the ISS. Hope this helps!

Comment: Where did you go? Come back to Space SE