# Which S-Band ISS antenna stopped transmitting to TDRS and was replaced during the recent 2021-12-02 EVA?

Tags: iss, eva, antenna, in-space-repairs

CNN's  says:

> Marshburn and Barron began their spacewalk at 6:15 a.m. ET, and it's expected to last for about six and a half hours. **The team will replace a malfunctioning communications antenna.**
>
> Live coverage of the spacewalk will stream on NASA TV and the agency's website.
> **The astronauts will replace an S-band Antenna Subassembly by using a spare that is already attached outside of the space station. The S-band radio frequencies are used to transmit low-rate voice and data from the space station more than 220 miles (354 kilometers) to flight controllers on the ground, according to NASA.**
>
> **After being operational for 21 years, the antenna recently stopped sending signals to Earth using NASA's Tracking and Data Relay Satellite System.** Mission managers discovered the issue in September, said Vincent LaCourt, NASA spacewalk flight director.
>
> "That timing allowed us to have Tom and Kayla go into our neutral buoyancy laboratory, or big pool where we practice spacewalks, and practice our exact spacewalk," LaCourt said.
>
> Overall, the loss of this antenna has a low impact on space station operations. However, maintaining antennas like this one allows for a redundancy in communications. **Installing the spare, which has existed outside the station since 2010, will allow that system of backups to continue.** The station has other low-rate S-band systems and high-rate KU-band systems that relay videos back and forth.

Since I ask a lot of antenna questions, I'm going to take a guess. The article says the communications it to TDRS satellites which are generally located in three clusters spaced out by about 120° in GEO and so will be

1. About 35,000+ km away.
2. Have an apparent motion as fast as about 360°/92 + (180/π) × 60 × (7.7/35,000) ≅ 3.9 + 0.8 = 4.7° per minute when it's directly above (the angular rate of ISS, plus correction for TDRS being closer than infinity).

So *I'm guessing* that we're looking for a medium gain antenna that is articulated, i.e. it constantly changes the direction that it's pointing.

It's obviously not this, from [@MarkAdler's answer to *What is the purpose of the rotating dish antenna on the ISS*](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/8742/12102) since it's moving at a way faster angular rate than the ISS orbits:

[image: RapidScan antenna on the ISS]

Here's a dish antenna that according to @OrganicMarble's answer is in storage on the outside of the ISS, ready to be retrieved during an EVA:

- [What is the function of this (apparently) fixed dish on the ISS?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21480/12102)

and here are the active dish antennas that can (be seen to) move (in the video) to maintain a link with TDRS satellites in GEO.

But these are Ku-band, higher frequency and so likely higher gain and bandwidth than an S-band antenna described in the article.

**Question:** Which S-Band ISS antenna stopped transmitting to TDRS and was replaced during the recent 2021-12-02 EVA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ISS has 2 S-band antenna support assemblies (SASAs). There is one on each of the S1 (Starboard 1) and P1 (Port 1) truss segments.

[image]

This EVA replaced the one on the P1 truss.

Source: Downloaded the official visualization package from https://vrlab.jsc.nasa.gov/doug/flight_packages/: It's called "US_EVA_P1_SASA_RR_v5.exe" which is a big clue right there.   Load it up in official NASA visualization software [DOUG](https://vrlab.jsc.nasa.gov/) and you can see cool animations of the whole EVA.  Here's the start of the actual antenna installation - after all the prep and movement has been done.

[image]

At the left of the image you can see the dialog box with all the EVA tasks / steps in order.

Confirmed as the P1 SASA by [NASASpaceflight.com](https://www.nasaspaceflight.com/2021/12/us-eva-78/) (emphasis mine)

> In September, a routine check of **the String-2 SASA on the P1 Truss** – which has been operating for the past 20 years – revealed that the return link had degraded, meaning the SASA could not provide any downlink to the ground. The uplink, however, continued to operate normally.
>
> Since the String-1 SASA continued to function, and with the Ku-band system providing a backup command and control capability, replacing the unit was not considered a priority.
>
> However, a high beta-angle period coming up in December could cause the fully operable String-1 SASA to reach its temperature limits and cease functioning, which would leave the ISS without any S-band downlink capability due to the degraded String-2 SASA.
>
> For this reason, ISS program managers decided to remove and replace the degraded SASA in order to restore redundancy prior to the high-beta period.

Read more about ISS comm antennas here: [Do antennae on the ISS have to constantly move to maintain data links?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/16569/do-antennae-on-the-iss-have-to-constantly-move-to-maintain-data-links/16570#16570)