# Why are there times when the ISS can transmit audio, but not video?

Tags: iss, data-transmission

I am watching the live stream of today(9/1/16)'s [spacewalk](http://gizmodo.com/watch-live-as-iss-astronauts-spacewalk-to-install-a-new-1785497722). The ISS entered a position in space where the video feed was lost, but they are still able to broadcast the audio conversations between the astronauts. How is it possible to only be able to transmit/receive one, and not the other?

(Apologies if this has been asked before, but nothing showed up in the search.)

Comment: Related: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/16569/do-antennae-on-the-iss-have-to-constantly-move-to-maintain-data-links https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/12296/when-does-the-iss-have-a-loss-of-signal/12301#12301

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Edit** after being pointed in the right direction by @Organic Marble:

Video goes out over the Ku-band link (which uses a very directional dish antenna), audio goes over a separate S-band link (which looks to be less directional, so less likely to go down).

Comment: 2 separate comm systems are involved.

Comment: You can see them very nicely in @OrganicMarble 's [answer here](http://space.stackexchange.com/a/16570/12102)!