# How many ways of communication with ground can ISS crew use?

Tags: iss, communication

I'm currently writing fictional story which is happening at ISS and I have so many questions about this topic, but this one is the most important to me. How many possibilities of communication they have? Is there's a special "communication place" for every space agenture at ISS or there's a just one big communication centre for all?

Comment: Try searching for ISS Communication on this site. There are many answered questions.

Comment: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/12296/when-does-the-iss-have-a-loss-of-signal

Comment: @OrganicMarble Thank you a lot, I'm new at this website and English isn't my first language, so I can get confused easily. I'm happy to discover SE, there's so much handy informations for me.

Comment: Welcome to Space Exploration!

Comment: @AnnaLorenzová these two links [**1**](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/communication+iss) and [**2**](https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bradio-communication%5D+%5Biss%5B) will give you searches for the `iss` tag combined with either the `communications` tag or the `radio-communications` tag. Take a look through those and see if you can get the general idea, I think a unique part of your question is the physical locations ons the ISS where different communications can happen. Is there a single "coms" center, or can people send messages from many locations.

Comment: Manually rotating the solar panels to broadcast in Morse Code?

Comment: [This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/23280/103) provides a pretty comprehensive list.

Comment: Add flashing a laser pointer to the list. Altering your course is another method. A "wing dip" is a traditional form of communication used by pilots: http://www.survivaloutdoorskills.com/searchandrescue.htm .